# SQL Query for finding an entry for a specific category

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a Relation in MySQL database which is as follows

```
|  id  |   name  |  category  |
```

where **category** will have value X,Y or Z.

**id** is set to **AUTO_INCREMENT** so that whenever I insert a row, it'll increase accordingly

The main motive here is to make a query which may return the entry with MAXIMUM **id** in a particular category, say Y.

For example, if there are following entries in the table:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|      id     |     name      |    category     |
-------------------------------------------------
|      1      |     abc       |       X         |
|      2      |     cde       |       X         |
|      3      |     efg       |       Y         |
|      4      |     ghi       |       X         |
|      5      |     ijk       |       Z         |
-------------------------------------------------
```

now the query must return the entry which has highest **id** and of category = X (i.e. the entry with id = 4).

P.S.: the query is intended to be used in PHP script as well.

Comment: You're not asking us to write the query for you, are you?

Comment: @JayBlanchard, nah, he wouldn't...

Comment: You have both MySQL and SQL Server tagged - the solution will vary based on the RDBMS.  Which one are you using?

Comment: Try the [`MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html) function.

Comment: You might want to look into SQL's `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: @eggyal, don't think he'll need to group, because he's querying for a specific category.

Comment: @shmosel: Good point.

Comment: @shmosel is there any other option than group by?

Comment: `highest id and of category = X (i.e. the entry with id = 3)` -- Why would the highest entry be ID 3?  Your data indicates that it should be 4.

Comment: @Siyual correction made!

Comment: @Lincoln, sure, just `SELECT MAX(...) FROM ... WHERE ... ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be this is useful

```
 select * from my_table where id in( 
   select max(id)
   from my_table 
   group by category);
```

Comment: This also works 
SELECT MAX(id) AS id, name, category 
FROM `sandbox`
GROUP BY category ORDER BY id

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you mean by "Must return the entry..." but if you just want to know the highest ID per category like you've (sorta) indicated then something like this should work for a table this simple:

```
    select Category, max(ID) ID from #TTable
    group by Category
```

and it returns something like this:

```
    Category  ID
    X          4
    Y          3
    Z          5
```

But if you need to know the name (which I imagine you probably do) then this doesn't do much for ya, but @ScaisEdge's query works fine for that. Depends what you need. Can't say much for the PHP script issue, nor if this works in MYSQL as well as im using SQL Server